# Operation without NumPy objects raises NumPy ValueError (the truth of an array...)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I get an error that I found has to be raised by NP:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

It occures in this line of code:

```
adjacent_food_sources = [field for field in self.map.food if (field['pos'] in adjacent_positions)]
```

The two involved variables are (from print):

```
# adjacent_positions - normal 2d list
[[240, 392], [239, 393], [238, 392], [239, 391], [240, 393], [240, 391], [238, 393], [238, 391]]

# self.map.food - normal list containing normal dicts
[{'food': 50, 'pos': (420, 267)}, {'food': 50, 'pos': (324, 69)}, {'food': 50, 'pos': (480, 368)}, {'food': 50, 'pos': (248, 443)}, {'food': 50, 'pos': (354, 32)}]
```

If I try to reproduce it in a shell, `adjacent_food_sources` becomes an empty list, as it should since none of the positions match.

Why does NP raise an error here? I do use it in other parts of my code, but here I clearly have pure, 'vanilla' python.

Python version: 3.2.5
NumPy version: 1.8.2

Comment: works for me in python2.7, maybe try updating numpy?

Comment: Are you sure it is plain vanilla?  `print(an_array)` can look a lot like a 2d list.  Something is performing a plain vanilla boolean operation (e.g. `if`) on a boolean array, most likely the result of a boolean test of an numpy array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on your observation that the problem arises when the 'pos' members become arrays:

With your positions nested list I can do:

```
In [308]: positions
Out[308]: 
[[240, 392],
 [239, 393],
 [238, 392],
 [239, 391],
 [240, 393],
 [240, 391],
 [238, 393],
 [238, 391]]
In [309]: (239,393) in positions # a tuple can't match a list
Out[309]: False
In [310]: [239,393] in positions   # normal list match
Out[310]: True
In [311]: np.array([239,393]) in positions
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-311-10ddf5047e75> in <module>()
----> 1 np.array([239,393]) in positions

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

In [312]: np.array([239,393]) == positions[0]
Out[312]: array([False, False], dtype=bool)
```

`in` translates to a `contrains` method, which in turn has to perform some sort of equality against each element in `positions`.  But an array applies the test element by element, returning a boolean array.  It's the incompatibility between that boolean array and the scalar true/false expectations of `contains` that produces the error.

Wrapping the `pos` value in `list()` should do the trick.  It will even allow for proper matching of tuples:

```
In [315]: list(np.array([239,393])) in positions
Out[315]: True
In [316]: list((239,393)) in positions
Out[316]: True
```

`array.tolist()` is better than `list(array)` if you want to make sure all elements of a (2d or higher) array are converted to a list, but here I think `list()` will do.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! I fixed my problem by making sure that the lists I want to compare are all actual `list`s, much like you did in line 316.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the probem:

The line of code I posted is inside a loop. During the first iteration, where the line is executed, everything is fine. However, towards the end of each iteration the `pos` member of each dict in `self.map.food` becomes a NP array.

I think when testing with `in`, NP wanted to tell me that I have to check if either any or all of the elements of `pos` are in `adjacent_positions`. NP apparently doesn't allow me to check whether `pos` itself is in `adjacent_positions`.

Comment: I've added an answer explaining why  `in` tests with array values will produce the error message.